# Optimize CSS Delivery

Tags: css, pagespeed-insights

Есть стандартная задача - оптимизировать загрузку CSS.

Есть ужатый (`/static/CACHE/css/1f37a94c2ab5.css)` и есть пару шрифтов, которые загружаются извне.

Со шрифтами я решил так:

```
<noscript id="deferred-styles">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css' %}">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">    
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" >
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700">
</noscript>
```

и такой скрипт:

```
<script>
  var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
    var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
    var replacement = document.createElement("div");
    replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(replacement)
    addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
  else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>
```

Но проблему это не решило. [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) ругается на ужатый файл, т.к. он не обрабатывается этим скриптом.

Но если я засуну и ужатый CSS в `<noscript></noscript>`, то ругаться будет на все CSS подключения, и при этом есть явная проблема с отрисовкой стилей - сперва загружается белая `html` страница без стилей, а затем происходит отрисовка.

Подскажите, как это решить правильно?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Правильно будет поместить в html-файл между тегами `style` критический для отображения первой 1000px страницы css. Сгенерировать его можно например этим сервисом https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.
А нормально, что сервис  отдаёт мне : body { color: #202020; } и больше ничего ?

Comment: https://www.sitelocity.com/critical-path-css-generator
Вот тут отдаёт нужный css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря подсказке @Andrey Fedorov удалось решить проблему, правда частично, следующим образом:

1. [Здесь](https://www.sitelocity.com/critical-path-css-generator) я получил т.н. critical-path-css.
2. Далее, следуя инструкции и здравому смыслу, разместил его внутри тегов `<head></head>`
3. Весь свой css, включая достаточно увесистый `1f37a94c2ab5.css` разместил перед , окружив
4. Разместил скрипт указанный мною в вопросе выше тэгов `<noscript></noscript>`

P.S. Так же, на сайте по ссылке есть готовый скрипт, куда нужно вставить линк к *.css, чтобы всё работало как надо.

P.P.S. Теперь ругается на тот же минифицированный файл, но только на десктопе. На мобиле всё отлично.